# How do I add roles to groups in Azure Active Directory with Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I've seen commands like `Get-AzRoleDefinition` but I believe that comes from the old module 'Active Directory'. Is there a command to add a role to a group in the new module 'AzureAD'?

I looked for documentation on Microsoft's website and couldn't find any. If you know of documentation, please attach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-AzRoleDefinition` is an Azure PowerShell Cmdlet which gets the definition of an Azure RBAC role. It is very different than PowerShell cmdlets for Azure AD.

What you are looking for is `Microsoft Graph PowerShell` Cmdlets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-1.0. You would need to find an appropriate PowerShell cmdlet there to accomplish what you are trying to do.